# Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libcdt5_2.38.0-12ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

I have the following issue:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libcdt5_2.38.0-12ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
W: Can not find PkgVer for 'libcdt5'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also I can't install / unistall / upgrade packages.

Tried:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The output:

```
Hit:1 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]         
Get:3 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]       
Ign:4 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages        
Ign:5 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages         
Ign:6 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:7 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons    
Ign:8 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages    
Ign:9 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages     
Get:10 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [199 kB]
Ign:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:13 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:4 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [593 kB]
Hit:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                  
Hit:15 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter xenial InRelease                     
Get:5 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [573 kB]
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Hit:17 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                               
Get:6 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [304 kB]
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Err:6 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Hash Sum mismatch
Get:7 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [205 kB]
Err:7 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:8 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [511 kB]
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:20 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease           
Get:9 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [494 kB]
Ign:21 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:23 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [2.717 B]
Get:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [163 kB]
Err:11 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:12 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [212 kB]
Err:12 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Get:13 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5.888 B]
Err:13 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Get:21 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3.324 B]
Err:21 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Hash Sum mismatch
Get:22 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4.688 B]
Err:22 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Fetched 3.469 kB in 1s (2.289 kB/s)           
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.gz  
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar.gz  
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Tried another commands like

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libcdt5_2.38.0-12ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
```

But nothing changes, I wold be glad of any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time trying, i solved this problem using this

```
sudo dpkg --purge libcdt5_2.38.0-12ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: do you know why is this happening? i have the same issue with Node.js V14. 

`dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.15.0-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/nodejs/api/perf_hooks.html', which is also in package nodejs-doc 12.19.0~dfsg-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_14.15.0-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`